# What do you call a task that requires cleverness?

Tags: single-word-requests

A task that requires creativity is called a creative task; how would you describe a task that requires cleverness?

Comment: "Tricky" would be my first thought.  Depends on how clever you want me to be.  "You want to farber the glibbox?  Well, that's tricky to do."

Comment: I think "tricky" is a generic term for something difficult or problematic. Something that requires skill to solve, but not necessarily cleverness. A tricky task can easily require creativity, strength, cunning, etc.

Comment: If asked how hard it might be to do something along these lines, I might reply to my team leader that "it requires thought" -- meaning it's not a mindless, plug-and-chug implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **puzzle**, defined as

> Something, such as a game, toy, or problem, that requires ingenuity and often persistence in solving or assembling.

With ingenuity defined as

> Inventive skill or imagination; cleverness.

this seems to fit your criteria, but it certainly isn't perfect, with the word puzzle tending less towards a task and more towards a game and often implying said game only has one correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but you can try **"intellectually challenging"** (assuming by "cleverness" you mean intelligence or smarts):

> challenging: difficult in an interesting or enjoyable way

(Longman)

Example:

> What makes a course **intellectually challenging**?

(http://www.stern.nyu.edu/portal-partners/center-innovation-teaching-learning/citl-services/workshops/whatmakesacourseintellectuallychalllenging)

Answer (score 0):

A task that requires creativity is called *a creative task*.

I'd call a task that requires cleverness *an intelligence test*,

or *a test of (my/your/his...) intelligence*, to make it less of the school room.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a **sophisticated** task.

Answer (score 0):

How about a **cerebral** task.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cerebral)

> Full Definition of CEREBRAL.
>   1a :  of or relating to the brain or the intellect
>   1b :  of, relating to, affecting, or being the cerebrum
>   2a :  appealing to intellectual appreciation 
>   2b :  primarily intellectual in nature

Answer (score 0):

How about *[brainteaser](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainteaser)*?

> a puzzle that is difficult to figure out or solve

Mirriam-Webster

Answer (score 0):

Consider **precision work**.

Example: *The incredible precision work of a watchmaker: You need hands like a surgeon for this stuff*.